# Rails ActiveRecord access record through has_many association using a different key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

## Scenario

I'm building an admin panel in Rails for an old app that i wrote a while ago therefore the database is not designed to work with *ActiveRecord*.

## The design

[image]

As you can see the foreign key which is used by the `Game` and `Refferal` table is NOT the `id` of the `User` but instead a column on the `User` which is called `steam_id`

The Rails Model:

- `User` class

  - `has_many :games, :foreign_key => 'player'`

## The problem

When i'm trying the following command:

`User.find(1).games`

the ActiveRecord is producing the following queries:

```
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Game Load (1012.0ms)  SELECT `games`.* FROM `games` WHERE `games`.`player` = '1'
```

As you can see on the second query it tries to find a game where the `player` column is equal to **`1`**.

Obviously this is not what I want. I want to get the game where the **`game.player`** is equal to **`user.steam_id`**

How can i fix that? And most importantly how can i also fix the `belongs_to` association?

## Considerations

The main website is already live and with active users. I cant just start redesigning the entire DB and the codebase itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the `primary_key` in the association:

`User` model:

```
has_many :games, primary_key: 'steam_id', foreign_key: 'player'
```

`Game` model:

```
belongs_to :user, primary_key: 'steam_id', foreign_key: 'player'
```

Now you should be able use `User.find(1).games`, which will query for user's games using `steam_id` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Run 2 separate queries:

```
user = User.find(1)
games = Games.where(player: user.stream_id)
```

Comment: Well,  this is probably the least destructive way. If there is no better option i will go with it. Its just that i wanted to utilize this ActiveRecord magic

Answer (score 0):

User class:

```
has_many :games, :foreign_key => 'player'
```

Game class:

```
belongs_to :player, class_name: 'User'
```

This might help you give a try.